# Percentage of satisfied customers

Tags: probability

I found the following task, while preparing for my exam, but I can't come up with a solution. Can someone help me?

Installer Meier has three employees. Manfred gets 20 percent, Norbert
30 percent and Otto 35 percent of the orders, and the rest of the orders are handled by Mr Meier himself. At Manfred, 30 percent of the customers are satisfied, at Norbert 80 percent, 75 percent for Otto and 90 percent for Mr. Meier.

a) What percentage of all customers are satisfied?

b) A customer is satisfied. What is the probability that Mr. Meier completed the customer's order?

So I started with:
Let the events $A_1$ be ”an order is completed by Manfred",

$A_2$:”a Order will be completed by Norbert",

$A_3$:”an order is completed by Otto",

$A_4$:”an order is completed by Mr. Meier"

and B:”A customer is satisfied"

We are also looking for $P(B)$. The following probabilities are known:
$P(A_1) = 0.2, P(A_2) = 0.3, P(A_3) = 0.35, P(A_4) = 0.15, P(B|A_1) = 0.3,
P(B|A_2) = 0.8, P(B|A_3) = 0.75$ and $P(B|A_4) = 0.9.$

Using the total probability theorem, I calculated that 69.8 percent of all customers are satisfied. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, $69.75\%$ is correct.

Comment: Part $b$ is now a routine application of Bayes Theorem.  You have the denominator (that's what you just computed).  What should the numerator be?

Comment: I think $ A_i$ is the proportion of the orders of employee $i$ gets. But the result is correct, which is $69.75\%$ exactly .

Comment: I think the numerator is P(B|A4) · P(A4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already solved the first subtask correctly and according to the comments you also have the second task. With Bayes theorem you get the probability that Mr. Meier completed the customer's order.
You calculated the denominator in subtask a and the numerator from your comment is also correct.
So you get: $$ P= \frac{0,9 \cdot 0,15}{0,6975} = 0,1935...=0,194$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.